# How to fetch data?

Tags: php, mysql

This statement gives error

> unable to fetch result from database

```
$res =$dbcon->exec("select *from tablename ");
$res->fetch();
```

Give an error.

Answer (score 2):

You need a space in your query:

```
$res = $dbcon->exec("select * from tablename");
```

Depending on what `$dbcon` is, you may need to use the query method instead (part of alok.kumar's answer):

```
$res = $dbcon->query("select * from tablename");
```

Referenece: http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php

Answer (score 2):

change only one query

```
          $res =$dbcon->exec("select *from tablename "); 
               to
                  $res =$dbcon->query("select *from tablename ");
```